# Continous integration for iphone xcode

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, continuous-integration, uiwebview

I would like to  implement continous integration on an iphone. I've read that I can use HUDSON, and would like an opinion if this this the best option.

[Continuous Integration for Xcode projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212999/continuous-integration-for-xcode-projects)

The cruise control option also looks interesting.

http://blog.jeffreyfredrick.com/2008/11/27/continuous-integration-for-iphonexcode-projects/

Integration testing will be done by

http://code.google.com/p/uispec/

Is this a valid choice.

Comment: I've used Cruise Control on .net before and it worked well :)

Comment: I've posted a short tutorial on how to setup and configure Hudson to compile XCode builds for iPhone
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871701/setting-up-hudson-for-iphone-builds

Comment: After Oracle took over Hudson, the name changed to Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Apple just released to OSX Mavericks a new continuous integration platform.

Have a look to this thread:
[Continuous Integration for Xcode projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212999/continuous-integration-for-xcode-projects/17097018#17097018)

and this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/300-Working_with_Bots/view_integration_results.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH4-SW1

Comment: We are migrating from a Jenkins/TestFlightApp solution to OS X Mavericks Continuous Integration. So far, I am really impressed. Easier to set up and maintain, and a really nice web UI for reviewing unit tests and downloading builds.