# Continuous Integration with Automated Functional Testing for iPhone Application

Tags: ios, deployment, continuous-integration

**What I need Actually?**

We create the iPhone application for Mobile & iPad and the code is always checked in to the repository.

1) When ever the code is checked in to the code repository, that has to under go the automation testing and confirm the build does not failed or the app itself will works as per teh functional test scripts.

2) If there is any Build failure, mail has to be triggered to the developers.

3) The build is sucess and automation scripts are executed and that is also passed, next step is to deploy to the apple store and submit for review, necessary information for apple store is made available in configuration files.

**Existing reference in stack overflow:**

```
Continuous Integration for Xcode projects?
**Reference**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212999/continuous-integration-for-xcode-projects/17097018#17097018

Continuous integration for iphone xcode
**Reference**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544119/continous-integration-for-iphone-xcode
```

Some of other references also was checked, which just give me the idea of how to execute functional script during code checkin, which is actual works like any CI tools likes Jenkins etc.

Above said reference are also discussed during 2009/2013, which are evry old.

**What is available when researched?**

I came to know about using using Hudson on the mac, which is very old version and not much supportive and also found Xcode OS X Server which is a product of apple itself where the reviews are not good and implementation is not feasible for my requirement.

Please share me the the approach of how to achieve this, also is that is possible to do CI process a one touch go for IOS, I found something similar to android with few confirmation from user.

At-least execution of Tests and creating an .ipa file in ios will be great.

Comment: I believe https://www.bitrise.io/ supports everything you mentioned, if you're looking for a hosted CI/CD platform. There's also an open source CLI you can use, useful for local debugging ( https://www.bitrise.io/cli ).