# automatically build, deploy and test on iphone device

Tags: iphone, xcode, command-line

Is there way to build iphone app on the command line with xcodebuild, then automatically deploy the app to a USB-connected iphone device and run some unit testing on device?

Right now, I can do this under xCode with "Build and Run", but I'm looking for solution to do this outside of the xCode GUI environment.

Thanks

Comment: The automatic building of iPhone applications has been addressed in these questions: [Command line compiling an iPhone Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358939/command-line-compiling-an-iphone-application), [Continuous Integration for Xcode projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212999/continuous-integration-for-xcode-projects), and [Best practice for setting up an automated build server for iphone apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837043/best-practice-for-setting-up-an-automated-build-server-for-iphone-apps).  However, I don't see much about installation there.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  Yes, these will take care of automated build, but I'm looking for solution that would push the build to a USB-connected iPhone and execute some test code.  I can do this manually through the "Build and Run" button under xCode, but I also want to automate the push-to-iphone-and-test step.  Right now, it looks like comment on Applescript is the way to go.

Comment: @bob did you ever find out a way to get this working? 10 years later and this is still one of the only posts that has the exact thing I'm looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can script Xcode using Applescript, and run Applescript scripts from the command line.

There more on how to script Xcode in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007082/tell-applescript-to-build-xcode-project).